# Trac Upgrade to 1.0.1 Wiki Attachment Issue

Tags: apache, trac

I've recently tried to upgrade my Trac from version 0.12.2 to version 1.0.1 by following the upgrade guide on the Trac website. It mentioned to remove the attachment folder for the ticket and wikis because the folder has been changed from /path/to/project/attachments to /path/to/project/files/attachments. So I backed up the attachment folder and after the upgrade I put it back into my project folder under files/attachment. 
When I try to access an attachment in the new trac environment it has trouble finding it. It's trying to look for the attachment in this

```
/path/to/project/files/attachments/fad/fadece229cc1ef23ce5f467cec5f4675cec7ace5ad7c148c
```

folder, and the file names are in hashed code like

```
b10a69f289e6ae408878d2286758a3121be4759.txt.
```

instead of its actual name. Any files that are uploaded after the upgrade will go into this folder instead of the respective Wiki or ticket folder like it used to do before my upgrade. Has anyone experienced this issue while doing the Trac upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to 1.x includes a file store redesign including changed file paths.

File names with path are hashs now, computed from user-supplied names, and no the lightly encoded names. Consequently the backup doesn't match the expected new paths at all - as you experienced.

The conversion of an existing attachment storage is part of the upgrade script, so you clearly misread the [upgrade guide](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUpgrade#Attachmentsmigratedtonewlocation). The removal was meant for attachment sub-directories not managed by Trac core, and as post-upgrade-cleanup.

You should rather leave the files and let the store get transformed for you. Ensure you read the logs of the upgrade process to notice delicate issues immediately.